# html parent content wont show up though to ngInclude anglurjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-transclude, angularjs-ng-include

I have these two template which is for tree view, I want to use the first approach but it seems that there is a problem or I've missed something.

**First Approach (desirable but does not work)** 
TreeTemplate.html

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="node in c.model" style="list-style-type: none;" ng-include="'/_Core/DirectiveCore/Tree/NodeTemplate.html'">
        {{node.text}} <!--It wont show up , the problem is here, any tags will not show up in result-->
    </li>
</ul>
```

NodeTemplate.html

```
<ul ng-if="node.nodes">
<li ng-repeat="node in node.nodes" style="list-style-type: none;" ng-include="'/_Core/DirectiveCore/Tree/NodeTemplate.html'">
    {{node.text}}
</li>
```

every thing in `<li></li>` in TreeTemplate.html wont show up thought to `ng-include`

**Second Approch (not desirable but works)**

TreeTemplate.html

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="node in c.model" style="list-style-type: none;" ng-include="'/_Core/DirectiveCore/Tree/NodeTemplate.html'">
   <!--there is not any tag here!-->
</li>
```

NodeTemplate.html

```
    {{node.text}}
<ul ng-if="node.nodes">
    <li ng-repeat="node in node.nodes" style="list-style-type: none;" ng-include="'/_Core/DirectiveCore/Tree/NodeTemplate.html'">
        {{node.text}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

please help me figure out what is happening.

Comment: just let me know if my answer works for you, and if not, what can I do to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ng-include` attribute is replacing everything inside the `li` with the content from `NodeTemplate`. This is why your `{{node.text}}` isn't showing up.

Your second approach is almost ideal, I don't get why you don't like it. From what I get, the `NodeTemplate` should be a single node inside your tree, which means it should be responsible for rendering the node text as well.

I would just remove `{{node.text}}` inside the `li` there, since it'll be replaced by the `ng-include`:

```
{{node.text}}
<ul ng-if="node.nodes">
  <li ng-repeat="node in node.nodes" style="list-style-type: none;" ng-include="'/_Core/DirectiveCore/Tree/NodeTemplate.html'" />
</ul>
```

Comment: Yeah, seems it is ideal as  you said..I am using the second approach and every thing is fine now..I wanted to know if It's a good approach or bad : )